# How to handle routing on an Angular app hosted through Elastic Beanstalk without hashing

Tags: angular, routes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am developing an Angular app and I have successfully published it to Elastic Beanstalk. The app works fine except when it comes to entering specific routes outside of the Angular app navigation.

For instance, if I enter `mywebsite.com/{some_url}` I am given a 404 error. Of course, if I enter `mywebsite.com`, it's fine because the server just serves `index.html` and the app loads. I understand that much.

I could live with my users just having to start at the root of the website if it weren't for a callback I need to handle. Users log in through a third-party authenticator before being redirected to my website with the callback. Of course, when this redirect uri is loaded, a 404 error is given since my Elastic Beanstalk installation doesn't know where to route this to.

[image: 404 Error from callback]

I need to figure out how I still use Elastic Beanstalk and Angular together so that I can enter specific URLs and have them load; or, at least have the callback load properly. I also don't want the hash method work-around. I want my pretty URLs, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was unexpected. Took a very roundabout way of figuring out exactly what I needed to do, but I finally figured out.

It's important to know what proxy server your Elastic Beanstalk instance is running. For me, the proxy server is actually Apache (I initially thought it was nginx). Once I figured out my proxy server was Apache, I referenced Angular's documentation about solving the SPA routing issue ([Server Configuration](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)) for Apache production servers. From there, I copied the recommended code into a file I called, `apache.config`, under the `.ebextensions` directory, as recommended by AWS' EB documentation.

From the base of my Angular project's directory, `.ebextensions/apache.config`:

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/spa_redirect.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            RewriteEngine On
                # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
                RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
                RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
                RewriteRule ^ - [L]
                # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
            RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

So ecstatic to have figured it out.

Comment: is "/etc/httpd/conf.d/spa_redirect.conf": needed here?

Comment: @EricHuang I haven't tried it without, but believe it is needed because it's the configuration file that Apache will look at (though you can probably change the name of the file if you would like, as long as it as the '.conf' extension)

Comment: @JoshuaKemmerer I'm having difficulty in deploying a basic angular app to elastic beanstalk. I want to deploy a simple app created using the angular-cli like so - 'ng new basic-app'. I haven't added anything extra to the app. I just want to host this on aws EB. I always end up getting npm install issues when I try and deploy this simple app.. Maybe I'm missing something trivial? I have no experience in developing/deploying front-end tech. Hoping you could help. Thanks

Comment: @NitinKumar No problem. Knowing what I know now, I would actually recommend placing your app on S3 rather than Elastic Beanstalk. As long as you're not doing any server-side rendering of your app, this should be adequate. All you have to do to get an Angular app public on S3 is to create the bundle files: `ng build --prod --aot --env=prod` (yours may differ if you don't want AoT), place them on S3, and make the bucket public.

Comment: @JoshuaKemmerer Thanks for replying! The reason I’m going with elastic beanstalk is because this application will grow to a point where server-side rendering may be required.

Comment: @NitinKumar I see. I believe the best platform for Angular on EB is actually PHP (that's what we used), so I would try that. Then, when you upload the .ZIP file with your Angular `/dist` files in it, include the `apache.config` file in a `.ebextensions` directory. I believe that was it. It's been a while since I've deployed to EB, so hopefully I'm not missing any extra steps.

Comment: @JoshuaKemmerer I was finally able to deploy the app! I'm serving the app through express js rather than angular deploying its development server via 'ng serve'. Seems to me that EB was having difficulties in install the angular cli dependencies. Thanks!

Comment: @NitinKumar Awesome! Glad you were able to get things to work. I just saw your LinkedIn request; feel free to reach out again for any Angular-related questions. Also, gitter.im is another good resource for Angular